# How to create fixed toolbar under another toolbar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to create toolbar under toolbar, first toolbar is not fixed, second bar is fixed, second bar fixed in the top of the screen like in the site: https://www.lingvolive.com/ru-ru/translate/en-ru/overflow. How to do it in angular with material.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do it:

```
<div>top toolbar</div>
<div style="position: sticky; top: 0; position: -webkit-sticky;">Sticky Toolbar</div>
```

```html
    <div>top toolbar</div>
        <div style="background-color: red; position: sticky; top: 0; position: -webkit-sticky;">Sticky Toolbar</div>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
        <p>Padding for scroll</p>
```

Comment: strange. I just tried it and it seems to work fine. make sure you have top: 0; included.

Comment: add "position: -webkit-sticky" for safari browsers.